# REST API call: Missing URI template variable 'productoId' for method parameter of type Long

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

Im trying to do a query in Spring boot to database (http://localhost:8180/products/2) and the server responds with:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Oct 26 01:29:12 COT 2017 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Missing URI template
>   variable 'productoId' for method parameter of type Long

This the interface

```
package com.beitech.orders.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.beitech.orders.model.Product;

public interface ProductJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

    Product findByProductoId(Long productoId);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCTO_ID = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Product findByproductoId3(Long productoId);

}
```

This is the controller:

```
package com.beitech.orders.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.beitech.orders.model.Product;
import com.beitech.orders.repository.ProductJpaRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

     @Autowired
     private ProductJpaRepository productJpaRepository;

     @GetMapping(value = "/allProducts")
     public List<Product> findAll(){
         return productJpaRepository.findAll(); 
     }

     @GetMapping(value = "/{productId}")
     public Product findByProductoId(@PathVariable final Long productoId){
         return productJpaRepository.findByProductoId(productoId); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you share some more layers of the stack trace?

Comment: Also, why are you using **final** Long productoId?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in that you use different names for path variable and method parameter (**productId** and **productoId**). Try to change annotation `@PathVariable` by specifying variable's name: `public Product findByProductoId(@PathVariable(name="productId") final Long productoId)`. But I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{productId}")

@PathVariable final Long productoId){
```

There is a mismatch there between `productId` and `productoId`. If you want `productId` to be bound to `Long productoId` then you would have to declare `@PathVariable(name="productId")` or alternatively just rename `productoId` to `productId` or vice versa.

Comment: I was tired and  I dont saw this mismatch. Thank you very much.